# how to setText of EditText attribute of autocompletetextview

Tags: android

```
if (view == View) {
        // Checking for empty roll number
        if (Rollno.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
            showMessage("Error", "Please enter Rollno");
            return;
        }
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE rollno='" + Rollno.getText() + "'", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            Name.setText(c.getString(1));
            Marks.setText(c.getString(2));



        }
        **if(c.moveToFirst()){
            Dept.setText(c.getString());
        }**

        else {
            showMessage("Error", "Invalid Rollno");
            clearText();
        }
    }
```

hello champs!!!!
i can't able to code "Dept" id of autocompletetextview
**Dept.setText(c.getString(3));**
Dept is id of EditText of nos 3.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to print `c.getString()` to see what the result is ,maybe the output is not what you are expecting, then i recommend you to change `Rollno.getText()` to `Rollno.getText().toString()`

Comment: i had set it Rollno.getText().toString() and also Rollno.getText().toString().toString()

Comment: but it get won't able to run the app get's crashed..

Comment: in my case the Dept Id of AutoCompleteTextView  when set as c.getString(3) coz of 3rd index is of AutoCompleteTextView then it still not working

Comment: i am sorry your explanation is not clear, i want to know what c.getString() return, and i want to see the error to understand what is the error.

Comment: i am posting a question newly with more clearence sorry for missconceptions.